Is it Possible to link a button widget to a map widget in thingsboard?
Can you link a button widget to a map widget?
If I create a button widget I want it to show different kinds of devices in the map when I press it.
For example: I have a number of devices on the map, some are active and some are inactive.
I want to use the button to filter out and only show inactive devices when I press it the first time and active devices when I press it a second time on the map.
Is it possible?
I have tried to ask Chatgpt for advice but have come up empty.
It gives me some examples on how to use "dashboard messages" using js code as a custom action.
For example:
self.onAction = function() {
**    // Send a custom message to the map widget
    self.ctx.widgetContext.sendDashboardMessage("updateMap", {
        filterKey: "deviceType",
        filterValue: "temperature"
    });
};**

Thats the button action and the map action it recommends is a follows:
**self.onDataUpdated = function() {
    // Listen for the "updateMap" message
    self.ctx.dashboard.on("updateMap", function(data) {
        var filterKey = data.filterKey;
        var filterValue = data.filterValue;

        // Example: Update the map widget datasource based on the received message
        self.ctx.updateAliases({
            filter: {
                key: filterKey,
                value: filterValue
            }
        });
    });
};**


Have tried both scripts and changed the parameters to the corresponding ones I have but cant get it to work.
Im kind of new to Thingsboard when it comes down to JS scripting and have trouble sometimes to get my head around the solutions.

example dashboard JSON (import it). instead of the widget card you can use a widget map
(thingsboard v3.7+)
{
      "title": "test",
      "image": null,
      "mobileHide": false,
      "mobileOrder": null,
      "name": "test",
      "configuration": {
        "description": "",
        "widgets": {
          "681c3372-dd71-35b7-2b15-cff77ce8a7ba": {
            "typeFullFqn": "system.cards.entities_table",
            "type": "latest",
            "sizeX": 7.5,
            "sizeY": 6.5,
            "config": {
              "timewindow": {
                "displayValue": "",
                "selectedTab": 0,
                "realtime": {
                  "realtimeType": 1,
                  "interval": 1000,
                  "timewindowMs": 86400000,
                  "quickInterval": "CURRENT_DAY",
                  "hideInterval": false,
                  "hideLastInterval": false,
                  "hideQuickInterval": false
                },
                "history": {
                  "historyType": 0,
                  "interval": 1000,
                  "timewindowMs": 60000,
                  "fixedTimewindow": {
                    "startTimeMs": 1729764181502,
                    "endTimeMs": 1729850581502
                  },
                  "quickInterval": "CURRENT_DAY",
                  "hideInterval": false,
                  "hideLastInterval": false,
                  "hideFixedInterval": false,
                  "hideQuickInterval": false
                },
                "aggregation": {
                  "type": "NONE",
                  "limit": 200
                }
              },
              "showTitle": true,
              "backgroundColor": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
              "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
              "padding": "4px",
              "settings": {
                "enableSearch": true,
                "enableSelectColumnDisplay": true,
                "enableStickyHeader": true,
                "enableStickyAction": true,
                "reserveSpaceForHiddenAction": "true",
                "displayEntityName": false,
                "displayEntityLabel": false,
                "displayEntityType": false,
                "displayPagination": true,
                "defaultPageSize": 10,
                "defaultSortOrder": "name",
                "useRowStyleFunction": false,
                "entitiesTitle": "Entities"
              },
              "title": "Entities table",
              "dropShadow": true,
              "enableFullscreen": true,
              "titleStyle": {
                "fontSize": "16px",
                "fontWeight": 400,
                "padding": "5px 10px 5px 10px"
              },
              "useDashboardTimewindow": false,
              "showLegend": false,
              "datasources": [
                {
                  "type": "entity",
                  "name": "",
                  "entityAliasId": "88982c4f-ae03-d54e-bbaf-c425ccab3c64",
                  "filterId": "a01dd946-02fe-bc3d-aeda-7bb4e8ebeaf4",
                  "dataKeys": [
                    {
                      "name": "name",
                      "type": "entityField",
                      "label": "Name",
                      "color": "#2196f3",
                      "settings": {},
                      "_hash": 0.8263202899500013
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "active",
                      "type": "attribute",
                      "label": "active",
                      "color": "#4caf50",
                      "settings": {
                        "customTitle": "",
                        "columnWidth": "0px",
                        "useCellStyleFunction": true,
                        "cellStyleFunction": "var active = value;\nvar color = 'black';\nif (active) {\n    if (active === \"false\") {\n      color = 'red';\n    } else {\n      color = 'green';\n    }\n}\nreturn {\n  fontWeight: 'bold',\n  color: color\n};\n",
                        "useCellContentFunction": false,
                        "useCellContentFunctionOnExport": true,
                        "cellContentFunction": "",
                        "defaultColumnVisibility": "visible",
                        "columnSelectionToDisplay": "enabled",
                        "columnExportOption": "onlyVisible"
                      },
                      "_hash": 0.4824152367772563,
                      "aggregationType": null,
                      "units": null,
                      "decimals": null,
                      "funcBody": null,
                      "usePostProcessing": null,
                      "postFuncBody": null
                    }
                  ],
                  "alarmFilterConfig": {
                    "statusList": [
                      "ACTIVE"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "displayTimewindow": false,
              "configMode": "advanced",
              "actions": {},
              "showTitleIcon": false,
              "titleIcon": "list",
              "iconColor": null,
              "titleFont": null,
              "titleColor": null,
              "enableDataExport": true
            },
            "row": 0,
            "col": 0,
            "id": "681c3372-dd71-35b7-2b15-cff77ce8a7ba"
          },
          "701db14b-f223-c3d2-14ba-773738aeff81": {
            "typeFullFqn": "system.toggle_button",
            "type": "rpc",
            "sizeX": 4,
            "sizeY": 2,
            "config": {
              "showTitle": true,
              "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
              "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
              "padding": "0px",
              "settings": {
                "initialState": {
                  "action": "GET_ATTRIBUTE",
                  "defaultValue": true,
                  "executeRpc": {
                    "method": "getState",
                    "requestTimeout": 5000,
                    "requestPersistent": false,
                    "persistentPollingInterval": 1000
                  },
                  "getAttribute": {
                    "scope": null,
                    "key": "active"
                  },
                  "getTimeSeries": {
                    "key": "state"
                  },
                  "dataToValue": {
                    "type": "NONE",
                    "dataToValueFunction": "/* Should return boolean value */\nreturn data;",
                    "compareToValue": true
                  }
                },
                "checkState": {
                  "action": "SET_ATTRIBUTE",
                  "executeRpc": {
                    "method": "setState",
                    "requestTimeout": 5000,
                    "requestPersistent": false,
                    "persistentPollingInterval": 1000
                  },
                  "setAttribute": {
                    "scope": "SERVER_SCOPE",
                    "key": "active"
                  },
                  "putTimeSeries": {
                    "key": "state"
                  },
                  "valueToData": {
                    "type": "CONSTANT",
                    "constantValue": true,
                    "valueToDataFunction": "/* Convert input boolean value to RPC parameters or attribute/time-series value */\nreturn value;"
                  }
                },
                "uncheckState": {
                  "action": "SET_ATTRIBUTE",
                  "executeRpc": {
                    "method": "setState",
                    "requestTimeout": 5000,
                    "requestPersistent": false,
                    "persistentPollingInterval": 1000
                  },
                  "setAttribute": {
                    "scope": "SERVER_SCOPE",
                    "key": "active"
                  },
                  "putTimeSeries": {
                    "key": "state"
                  },
                  "valueToData": {
                    "type": "CONSTANT",
                    "constantValue": false,
                    "valueToDataFunction": "/* Convert input boolean value to RPC parameters or attribute/time-series value */ \n return value;"
                  }
                },
                "disabledState": {
                  "action": "DO_NOTHING",
                  "defaultValue": false,
                  "getAttribute": {
                    "key": "state",
                    "scope": null
                  },
                  "getTimeSeries": {
                    "key": "state"
                  },
                  "dataToValue": {
                    "type": "NONE",
                    "compareToValue": true,
                    "dataToValueFunction": "/* Should return boolean value */\nreturn data;"
                  }
                },
                "autoScale": true,
                "horizontalFill": true,
                "verticalFill": false,
                "checkedAppearance": {
                  "type": "outlined",
                  "showLabel": true,
                  "label": "Active",
                  "showIcon": true,
                  "icon": "mdi:lock-open-variant",
                  "iconSize": 24,
                  "iconSizeUnit": "px",
                  "mainColor": "#198038",
                  "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
                  "borderRadius": "4px",
                  "customStyle": {
                    "enabled": null,
                    "hovered": null,
                    "pressed": null,
                    "activated": null,
                    "disabled": null
                  }
                },
                "uncheckedAppearance": {
                  "type": "filled",
                  "showLabel": true,
                  "label": "Inactive",
                  "showIcon": true,
                  "icon": "lock",
                  "iconSize": 24,
                  "iconSizeUnit": "px",
                  "mainColor": "#D12730",
                  "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
                  "borderRadius": "4px",
                  "customStyle": {
                    "enabled": null,
                    "hovered": null,
                    "pressed": null,
                    "activated": null,
                    "disabled": null
                  }
                },
                "background": {
                  "type": "color",
                  "color": "#fff",
                  "overlay": {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "color": "rgba(255,255,255,0.72)",
                    "blur": 3
                  }
                },
                "padding": "12px"
              },
              "title": "Active/Inactive",
              "dropShadow": true,
              "enableFullscreen": false,
              "widgetStyle": {},
              "actions": {
                "headerButton": [
                  {
                    "name": "hjgh",
                    "icon": "more_horiz",
                    "useShowWidgetActionFunction": null,
                    "showWidgetActionFunction": "return true;",
                    "type": "custom",
                    "customFunction": null,
                    "openInSeparateDialog": false,
                    "openInPopover": false,
                    "id": "15c91fcf-78c3-b63d-d1f0-14db88811b97"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "widgetCss": "",
              "noDataDisplayMessage": "",
              "titleFont": {
                "size": 16,
                "sizeUnit": "px",
                "family": "Roboto",
                "weight": "500",
                "style": null,
                "lineHeight": "1.6"
              },
              "showTitleIcon": false,
              "titleTooltip": "",
              "titleStyle": {
                "fontSize": "16px",
                "fontWeight": 400
              },
              "pageSize": 1024,
              "titleIcon": "home",
              "iconColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
              "iconSize": "24px",
              "configMode": "basic",
              "targetDevice": {
                "type": "entity",
                "entityAliasId": "76e8f1e3-a64f-f30b-c4a1-be5ce8e12b9d"
              },
              "titleColor": null,
              "borderRadius": null,
              "datasources": []
            },
            "row": 0,
            "col": 0,
            "id": "701db14b-f223-c3d2-14ba-773738aeff81"
          }
        },
        "states": {
          "default": {
            "name": "test",
            "root": true,
            "layouts": {
              "main": {
                "widgets": {
                  "681c3372-dd71-35b7-2b15-cff77ce8a7ba": {
                    "sizeX": 7,
                    "sizeY": 11,
                    "row": 0,
                    "col": 0
                  },
                  "701db14b-f223-c3d2-14ba-773738aeff81": {
                    "sizeX": 4,
                    "sizeY": 2,
                    "row": 0,
                    "col": 17
                  }
                },
                "gridSettings": {
                  "layoutType": "default",
                  "backgroundColor": "#eeeeee",
                  "columns": 24,
                  "margin": 10,
                  "outerMargin": true,
                  "backgroundSizeMode": "100%"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "entityAliases": {
          "88982c4f-ae03-d54e-bbaf-c425ccab3c64": {
            "id": "88982c4f-ae03-d54e-bbaf-c425ccab3c64",
            "alias": "all",
            "filter": {
              "type": "entityType",
              "resolveMultiple": true,
              "entityType": "DEVICE"
            }
          },
          "76e8f1e3-a64f-f30b-c4a1-be5ce8e12b9d": {
            "id": "76e8f1e3-a64f-f30b-c4a1-be5ce8e12b9d",
            "alias": "current user",
            "filter": {
              "type": "singleEntity",
              "resolveMultiple": false,
              "singleEntity": {
                "entityType": "CURRENT_USER",
                "id": "13814000-1dd2-11b2-8080-808080808080"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "a01dd946-02fe-bc3d-aeda-7bb4e8ebeaf4": {
            "id": "a01dd946-02fe-bc3d-aeda-7bb4e8ebeaf4",
            "filter": "current user",
            "keyFilters": [
              {
                "key": {
                  "type": "SERVER_ATTRIBUTE",
                  "key": "active"
                },
                "valueType": "BOOLEAN",
                "predicates": [
                  {
                    "keyFilterPredicate": {
                      "operation": "EQUAL",
                      "value": {
                        "defaultValue": false,
                        "dynamicValue": {
                          "sourceType": "CURRENT_USER",
                          "sourceAttribute": "active",
                          "inherit": false
                        }
                      },
                      "type": "BOOLEAN"
                    },
                    "userInfo": {
                      "editable": true,
                      "label": "",
                      "autogeneratedLabel": true,
                      "order": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "editable": true
          }
        },
        "timewindow": {
          "displayValue": "",
          "hideAggregation": false,
          "hideAggInterval": false,
          "hideTimezone": false,
          "selectedTab": 0,
          "realtime": {
            "realtimeType": 0,
            "interval": 1000,
            "timewindowMs": 60000,
            "quickInterval": "CURRENT_DAY",
            "hideInterval": false,
            "hideLastInterval": false,
            "hideQuickInterval": false
          },
          "history": {
            "historyType": 0,
            "interval": 1000,
            "timewindowMs": 60000,
            "fixedTimewindow": {
              "startTimeMs": 1729764156901,
              "endTimeMs": 1729850556901
            },
            "quickInterval": "CURRENT_DAY",
            "hideInterval": false,
            "hideLastInterval": false,
            "hideFixedInterval": false,
            "hideQuickInterval": false
          },
          "aggregation": {
            "type": "AVG",
            "limit": 25000
          }
        },
        "settings": {
          "stateControllerId": "entity",
          "showTitle": false,
          "showDashboardsSelect": true,
          "showEntitiesSelect": true,
          "showDashboardTimewindow": true,
          "showDashboardExport": true,
          "toolbarAlwaysOpen": true
        }
      }
    }


Thanks alot, I will try this solution.
